# After opening and closing a folder, I am unable to rename it if it contains an executable

Tags: windows-7, rename

Windows 7 x64 user.

If I try to rename a folder after opening and closing it, and that folder contains an executable, Windows will deny the operation with a "Folder in use" message.

If I don't open the folder beforehand the problem doesn't appear.

Fortunately the problem persists only for a few dozen seconds. After enough time passes, I can rename the folder without any problem. Unless of course I open and close it again...

I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

EDIT: If I try to delete the folder, a "Folder Access Denied" window pops up, saying that I need permission from myself to perform that action. I tried using a software called TakeOwnershipEx to take permission of the folder, but to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like your antivirus software is scanning the EXEs and locking the folder. Does disabling the appropriate antivirus feature help?

Comment: Disabled the antivirus completely. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on the site. It's a small piece of software that tells you what program is marking a file as "in use". I found it because I thought windows indexing might be giving you fits. If the directory is actively being indexed I could see that being an issue. But it looks like this little program in the link below might shed some light on it.

[How can I rename files and folders in Windows that are in use?](https://superuser.com/questions/54193/how-can-i-rename-files-and-folders-in-windows-that-are-in-use)

Comment: Thanks. The folders are locked by the System process,  PID 4. Oh, and indexing (I assume you are referring to Windows Search) is disabled.