# Why can't you change the name of an open file in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have to change file names a lot, but Windows won't let you change them when they're open. I know I can exit and rename the file after, or Save As with a different name, but this just seems like bad design.

Is anyone aware of a better workaround?

Comment: None that I have ever found,

Comment: Related: [How can I rename files and folders in windows that are in use?](https://superuser.com/questions/54193/how-can-i-rename-files-and-folders-in-windows-that-are-in-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is false. Files cannot be renamed if they are **intentionally locked**, a feature of many operating systems, including Linux and Windows, to prevent unpredictable results when trying to **write** to a file.

However, many applications, such as [Notepad++ (NPP)](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), can open a file **read-only**, not requiring a lock. Test this yourself: open a file in NPP and, with the file left open, rename it.

For your edification, you can peruse the [Windows OpenFile constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile), such as:

- **OF_READWRITE** - Opens a file with read and write permissions.
- **OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE** - Opens a file but allows other processes read and write acces.
- **OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE** - Opens a file, denying both read and write access to other processes.